# Checking BIN numbers from <list> + Performance enhancement

Tags: c#, performance, logic

Good day

I need to make my code run faster. I need to check 7 million records at a time and it takes between 1 and 3ms to do the following check. I was hoping somone give me advise on how to get this faster.

Before the below code I do a select to preload the bank_issuer class(this happens ones)  and load the tmpCard for a file (.txt).

```
 //golbal in class
 private List<bank_issuer> bank_issuer_list { get; set; }

          //code that I need help with

           for (int i = 10; i >= 1; i--)
            {
             string card_nr = tmpCard.card_number.Substring(0, i);

             foreach (bank_issuer item in bank_issuer_list)
              {
                if (card_nr.ToString() == item.bi_issuer.ToString().Trim())
                 {
                   issuer_found = true;
                   tmpcard.bp_id = item.bp_id;
                   break;
                 }
              }
              if (val_issuer_found)
               {
                  break;
               }                 
            }

class bank_issuer
{
    public string bi_issuer { get; set; }
    public string bp_id { get; set; }

    public bank_issuer(string bi_issuer, string bp_id)
    {
        this.bi_issuer = bi_issuer;
        this.bp_id = bp_id;
    }
    public bank_issuer()
    {
    }
}
```

Notes: 
The first for loop starts at 10 as a per system design. I am looking into getting it smaller.

Comment: Class definitions, please. Also, if you have _working code_, it might be better suited to [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: `card_nr.ToString()` is redundant since it is already a string. `item.bi_issuer` is probably also a string. Appart from that the code does not compute much heavy work.  I doubt it gets much faster from that.

Comment: Thanks, John ill look into "code review" and I have added the Bank_issuer class, The other class may be too big to show here.

Comment: As is `bi_issuer.ToString()` for the same reason.

Comment: Does the .ToString, that is extra, create overhead? or is it more of a "you should not do that"

Comment: @JacoVanDeventer: Test it :)

Comment: @Jaco [string.ToString()](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/string.cs#L2696-L2705)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do 3 things:

1. Trim your `bi_issuer` field in the constructor of `bank_issuer` - there's no point doing it every time. I don't know if you need to do it, but If it doesn't need trimming, don't do it at all.
2. Create a dictionary from your bank issuer list to leverage key hashing (`var bankIssuers = bank_issuer_list.ToDictionary(bi => bi.bi_issuer);`) - do this outside any loops, before you begin the process, and use this dictionary for lookups.
3. Change your method to use the dictionary:

-

```
for (int i = 10; i >= 1; i--)
{
    string card_nr = tmpCard.card_number.Substring(0, i);
    if (bankIssuers.TryGetValue(card_nr, out var issuer))
    {
        issuer_found = true;
        tmpcard.bp_id = issuer.bp_id;
        break;   
    }
}
```

Now, I don't know about the code around all of this, or the environment it's running in, etc. but you could also potentially use parallelism (but don't go into using it blind since there can be issues if code isn't self contained, if you use non-self contained code that isn't thread-safe).

Imagining the code above is in a method `bool TryPopulateIssuer(card tmpcard)`, and comes from a list of cards: `List<card> cards`, you could write code like this:

```
Parallel.ForEach(cards, card => {
    if (!TryPopulateIssuer(card))
    {
        // do something on failure to find the issuer
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi, John, I have implemented point 1 so far. I have a question regarding .ToDictionary. Will this only affect the class order. Or will this also change the order of the values inside the classes  bi_id; I am scared this will change the "key pairs" that i made when creating the classes.

Comment: `.ToDictionary()` simple creates a dictionary object - it doesn't affect the object you're making it from. `.ToDictionary(bi => bi.bi_issuer)` will create a dictionary of `issuer` -> `bank_issuer` object.

Comment: Thanks a lot don't think i want to dip into the parallelism blindly will discuss that with the "boss" :p